How can reduce flutter apk size?
i get following result when i try this command :
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64 --analyze-size
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (49.1MB).
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
app-release.apk (total compressed)                                         49 MB
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
META-INF/
    CERT.SF                                                                25 KB
    CERT.RSA                                                              1020 B
    MANIFEST.MF                                                            23 KB
  classes.dex                                                               1 MB
  lib/
    arm64-v8a                                                              26 MB
    Dart AOT symbols accounted decompressed size                            7 MB
      package:flutter                                                       3 MB
      dart:core                                                           319 KB
      dart:ui                                                             255 KB
      dart:typed_data                                                     207 KB
      dart:io                                                             181 KB
      dart:collection                                                     160 KB
      dart:async                                                          150 KB
      package:dbus                                                        132 KB
      package:get                                                          93 KB
      package:mahabharat_app                                               93 KB
      package:flutter_spinkit                                              92 KB
      dart:ffi                                                             73 KB
      package:go_router                                                    69 KB
      dart:convert                                                         69 KB
      package:just_audio/
        just_audio.dart                                                    56 KB
      package:source_span                                                  44 KB
      package:flutter_cache_manager                                        43 KB
      package:sqflite_common                                               38 KB
      package:audio_session                                                38 KB
      package:flick_video_player                                           35 KB
    armeabi-v7a                                                            18 MB
  assets/
    flutter_assets                                                          3 MB
    hrtfs                                                                  54 KB
    lua                                                                    55 KB
  AndroidManifest.xml                                                       2 KB
  res/
    33.9.png                                                                2 KB
    74.png                                                                  1 KB
    CG.png                                                                 67 KB
    D2.png                                                                 40 KB
    ER.9.png                                                                2 KB
    FM.9.png                                                                1 KB
    J6.9.png                                                                2 KB
    Mr.9.png                                                                1 KB
    Pi.9.png                                                                3 KB
    Q11.9.png                                                               3 KB
    SD.png                                                                 12 KB
    Vq.png                                                                  1 KB
    color-v23                                                               2 KB
    color                                                                   5 KB
    e1.xml                                                                  1 KB
    eB.9.png                                                                2 KB
    gV.9.png                                                                1 KB
    jy.png                                                                 20 KB
    kg.png                                                                  1 KB
    r9.png                                                                  2 KB
    tj.9.png                                                                2 KB
    u3.png                                                                  6 KB
    wi.9.png                                                                2 KB
    wi1.9.png                                                               1 KB
    ya.xml                                                                  1 KB
  resources.arsc                                                          309 KB
  kotlin/
    collections                                                             1 KB
    kotlin.kotlin_builtins                                                  5 KB
    ranges                                                                  1 KB
    reflect                                                                 1 KB
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒



check here steps to reduce apk size https://blog.flutter.wtf/flutter-app-binary-size/     and                                 https://medium.com/@panuj330/pushing-flutter-to-the-limit-the-ultimate-guide-to-reducing-flutter-app-size-4eb05c4351d1

With the following command, you can get output based on different architectures, and the size of each one is smaller.
In the terminal of VsCode:
flutter build apk --split-per-abi

